# Get a list of values from PLSQL procedure

Tags: java, oracle, plsql

I'm newbie in Java and PLSQL. I've build this procedure in PLSQL:

```
    PROCEDURE getLogs (
    p_idcontract            IN          NUMBER,
    p_iduser                IN          NUMBER,
    o_logs                  OUT         VARCHAR2
  )
  IS   
  BEGIN
      SELECT logData INTO o_logs
      FROM SERVICELOG 
      WHERE IDCONTRACT= p_idcontract 
      AND IDUSER= p_iduser;

  END getLogs;
```

If script detect several rows, return to the Java class who launch it this message:

> ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows

Please, how I can return an hashmap or similar, ready to be outputted to Java? Thanks.

Comment: You need a `cursor`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use ref cursor as an output parameter then build map inside java program. https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/using-ref-cursors-to-return-recordsets 
You can also define a user type in oracle that will be something like Java Array.

```
    PROCEDURE getLogs (
    p_idcontract            IN          NUMBER,
    p_iduser                IN          NUMBER,
    p_recordset OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
  )
  IS   
  BEGIN
 OPEN p_recordset FOR
      SELECT logData 
      FROM SERVICELOG 
      WHERE IDCONTRACT= p_idcontract 
      AND IDUSER= p_iduser;

  END getLogs;
```

Java code:

```
CallableStatement stmt = conn.prepareCall("BEGIN getLogs(?, ?, ?); END;");
      stmt.setInt(1, 0);
      stmt.setInt(2, 0);
      stmt.registerOutParameter(3, OracleTypes.CURSOR);
      stmt.execute();
      ResultSet rs = ((OracleCallableStatement)stmt).getCursor(3);
      while (rs.next()) {
        ;
       //here build your Map, list or whatever you want
      }
```

Comment: PLease can you share me a sample?

Comment: I've edited answer to add tutorial link how to use ref cursor.

Comment: Thanks. Now I got this error: "PLS-306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'GETLOGS'". Could be an error "java side", while defining the p_recordset as ARRAY?

Comment: It is not an Array. In link I've posted you have a Java code example how to read values from ref cursor. If you returned ref cursor you need to build array on java side by going throug ResultSet.

Comment: Work like a charm. Thanks!!